# What is the probability that the dice drawn was one with $6$ points on all sides?

Tags: probability

(a) In a container there are $10$ real dice, and $10$ dice, at which each of the six sides occurs with the same probability in a throw, but at $5$ of these dice two sides each have $2$, $4$ and $6$ points and with the last $5$ dice all sides have $6$ points. One of these $20$ dice is drawn at random from the container. This die is thrown $n$ times and a $6$ is thrown each time (without seeing the other sides). What is the probability that the dice drawn was one with $6$ points on all sides?

(b) How many of the real dice (with $6$ different sides) have to be in the container so that the probability that the dice drawn is a real one is equal to the probability that one with $6$ points on all sides was drawn? (Again under the fact that $6$ was rolled $n$ times.) How many is that for $n = 2$?

$$$$

For question (a) :

We consider the events :

S = A "6" is thrown

A = The "6" was from one of the dice with $6$ points on all sides

B = The "6" was from one of the dice with two sides each have $2$, $4$ and $6$ points

C = The "6" was from one of the normal dice

The probability that the "6" we got is from one of the dice with $6$ points on all sides is equalto
\begin{align*}P(A\mid S)&=\frac{P(A\cap S)}{P(S)}=\frac{1}{P(S\mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(S\mid B)\cdot P(B)+P(S\mid C)\cdot P(C)}\\ & =\frac{1}{1\cdot \frac{5}{20}+\frac{2}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{20}+\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{10}{20}}\\ & =\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}}\\ & =\frac{1}{ \frac{5}{12}}\\ & =\frac{12}{5}\end{align*} I must have done something wrong since the result is greater than  $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you used is correct, however you wrote $P(A \cap S) = 1$ in the numerator which is not true. It holds that $P(A \cap S) = P(A)$ in this case because $S$ will automatically occur when $A$ is true (or in "mathematical terms": $A \subset S$). Therefore your numerator should be $\frac{5}{20}$ instead. With that you would get:
$$\frac{\frac{5}{20}}{\frac{5}{12}} = \frac{12}{20} = 0.6$$

Comment: Ahh yes! So this is the probability that we get "6" from one with 6 points on all side, but at the first time. Since we roll $n$ times, and each timeis independent the result is $0.6^n$, or not?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: As for (b) : We want that $P(A\mid S) = P(C\mid S)$ and so we get $$\frac{P(A\cap S)}{P(S)}=\frac{P(C\cap S)}{P(S)} \Rightarrow \frac{P(A)}{P(S\mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(S\mid B)\cdot P(B)+P(S\mid C)\cdot P(C)}=\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{P(S\mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(S\mid B)\cdot P(B)+P(S\mid C)\cdot P(C)}$$ So do we consider that there are in total $20$ dice and we want to checkhow many of these have to be real or is the total number in this case also unknown?

Comment: The first thing is that we can drop the denominator and have to check just $P(A \cap S) = P(C \cap S)$. For my understanding it is now not clear if we should keep the total number of dice at $20$ or if we should keep the number of "only-six-dice" at $5$. If we change the total number of dice we get $P(A) = \frac{5}{n}$ and we have $P(C \cap S) = \frac{m}{6n}$ where $m$ is the number of real dices. If the total number stays at 20 we would have to change the number of "only-six-dices" because intuitively it is clear that the number of real dice has to be six times as high as the "only-six-dice"

Comment: And are both cases solvable? Imean if we change the total number we have two unknown variables, is it still possible to be solved?

Comment: Yes since $\frac{5}{n} = \frac{m}{6n} \Leftrightarrow 5 = \frac{m}{6}$

Comment: So we need $30$ real dices, right? This result is independent from the number of times we get $6$, or not? Because there is also question at the end "How many is that for $n=2$ ? "  So if we roll twice the dice and get both times a "6" we need again 30 real dice, right?

Comment: As far as I understand the exercise you are right about that

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)